# In NetworkManager, my nm-dispatcher is never called

Tags: networking, network-manager

I've got two Ubuntu laptops (both 10.10).
One is a new Maverick install and the other has been upgraded many times since 9.04.

On the latter, setting up a custom script hook in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` worked instantaneously.

However, on the older laptop, I can't get nm-dispatcher to get called, or at least to execute its hooks.

I've tried to run

```
NetworkManager --no-daemon -log-level=DEBUG
```

But there is no mention of nm-dispatcher.

How can I

1. Have a look at the source (I looked into the [git repo](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/network-manager/trunk/files/head:/src) but could not find anything.
2. find why the nm-dispatcher never gets called.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to look into the source code to fix this; the dispatcher runs the scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d` until it completes or until one of them returns with an error. This was the case on a few releases, because the initial dispatcher (`01ifupdown`) didn't understand the `vpn-up` and `vpn-down` (or `hostname`, even) states.

You'll be able to see what's happening from the logs in `/var/log/syslog`; they will contain a line such as:

```
Nov 5 21:38:57 chris-laptop nm-dispatcher.action: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' exited with error status 1.
```

This particular issue has been fixed now; but if you're still having issues you should consider filing a bug, or the obvious stuff like verifying permissions (as in, whether the script is executable).

Comment: May still related to [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/270630)?